# Push notification not working on production server but working from localhost

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

We use [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp)  library to send push notification's to android and iOS devices.

Sometime back push notification where working on our production server but stopped working for some reason and when we test it from localhost then we are able to send push notifications to iOS devices but not from the server itself.

It is hard to troubleshoot this issue as we have checked following

Ports 59112, 2195 and 2196 are open and confirmed by the server admin and when we try from the server it self telnet connectivity seems to for testing example [image]

When i try cmd from `telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195` it shows a blank screen i am not sure if it means it is working but i don't get any errors such as connection refused.

So far we have following check on server

- Ports open
- Certificate configured as it working properly

I am not sure what could be the other reason for push notification not working on server & working from local-host.

Logically it should fail from local-host as no certificates are configured on local machine.

Not sure what could be the issue.

we even tried online port tester they always show above ports closed so really confused with whole scenario

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: It was resolved by the developer, It seemed there was some sort of bug in the coding which they didn't agree to. From Your side make sure Port are open and you have configured the certificate for ios properly on your server. Rest i cant comment as i am not iOS developer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329040/pushsharp-apns-production-the-credentials-supplied-to-the-package-were-not-reco?rq=1