# PushSharp Exception : The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, pushsharp

I'm getting the below exception for IOS Push Notification using Pushsharp.I searched many articles but didn't get clear idea how to proceed.. Andoid working fine only problem with this IOS.

**Exception:**

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at PushSharp.Apple.FeedbackService.Run(ApplePushChannelSettings settings, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at PushSharp.Apple.ApplePushService.<ApplePushService>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__1(Object state)}
```

**MY Code:**

```
    PushBroker push = new PushBroker();
    push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
    push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
    push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
    push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
    push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
    push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
    push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
    push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;
    var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Data\abc\Cert\CCDevelopment.p12"); 
    push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, appleCert, "password")); //Extension method
   push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()                                                                      .ForDeviceToken("tokenId") //dev
                                 .WithAlert(msg) //load
                                 .WithBadge(1));  //
```

Answer (score 4):

I've figured the problem. I've revoked and regenerated the certificate again, and this time, I've only exported the private key (without the certificate) in Keychain access, exported as .p12 and used the new file, and it worked. For some reason, PushSharp wasn't playing well with .p12 when both certificate and private key was present in the file.

Referral Link
[PushSharp APNS production: The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized (development works fine though)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329040/pushsharp-apns-production-the-credentials-supplied-to-the-package-were-not-reco)

Answer (score 0):

When using the windows certificate store, (imho the easiest way to manage certificates on a production server), be sure to set the correct permissions on the private key.

Answer (score 0):

after 4 hours of testing:

convert the `.p12` to `.pem`, and it will work with IIS  limited users....