# Encrypt and decrypt using certificates in .NET Core C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate

With C#, I want to be able to Decrypt data using a certificate. However in .NET Core (3.1) I am unable to use the certificate to decrypt. Interestingly, it works fine in .NET Framework (4.8). In .NET Core, I can find and see the certificate, but when I try to cast it to a `RSACryptoServiceProvider` the result is always `NULL`. No issues at all in .NET Framework when I do the same thing.

I am creating a certificate using the `makecert.exe` utility like so:

```
makecert.exe -r -pe -n "CN=MyCert" -ss my -sr localmachine -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -len 2048 -e 01/01/2024 -sky Exchange C:\temp\MyCert.cer
```

Did something change in .NET Core with regards to certificates? Or am I missing something?

```
X509Certificate2 myCert = null;
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "72A5303B5CB3EF70BEC360E29FA5E9D86886EA44", false);
if (certCollection.Count == 1)
{
    myCert = certCollection[0];
}
else
{
    return;
}

var rsakey = (RSA)myCert.PrivateKey;
// In .NET Core rsp is always null
var rsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)rsakey;
```

I have tried various other approaches in similar StackOverflow questions, but to no avail.

Comment: Write some debug messages to a log file to see where the program is going and where its breaking down.  Should make for a fairly easy solve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Framework x509Certificate2 Class, HasPrivateKey == true && PrivateKey == null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730596/net-framework-x509certificate2-class-hasprivatekey-true-privatekey-nu)

Comment: @bartonjs Kind of? I think, one of the answers did mention using `myCert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` as per the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao, according to MSDN example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2?view=netcore-3.1) to get private key in .NET Core 3.1 you have to call `myCert.GetRSAPrivateKey()`.