# The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized (development works fine though)

Tags: c#, ios, amazon-ec2, apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

I am not getting notifications from APNS.  I have hosted my .Net API code on EC2 instance.  I have checked for :

1. Port 2195 and 2196 are open.
2. I have created p.12 properly as described  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329040/pushsharp-apns-production-the-credentials-supplied-to-the-package-were-not-reco/23340352)

Answer (score 0):

There was and issue related to Application Pool id type. I changed it to 'Network Service'.